# CSS "Header Nav a" Hover Over Font Colour Change without Script

Tags: html, css, fonts, hover

I have read at least 5 other questions and tried the answers, and other similar questions and answers and tried to adjust the code to fit in with mine but it just won't work.

The code is for an eBay product description, so it cannot contain any script/active content.

All I need is for my header links to change to black when hovered over. It is **not** a list.

I do have a list navigation in a sidebar and I managed to produce the hover effect on that just fine with the following css:

```
nav ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
ul li a {
  display:block;
}

ul li a:hover, ul li a:focus {
  color: #000000;
}
```

The HTML code for the Header Nav Links I need to add the hover to is:

```
<body>
  <div id="mainwrapper">
    <header> 
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Store logo">
        <nav>
          <a href="https://example.com" title="About Us">About Us</a>
          <a href="https://example.com" title="FAQ">FAQ</a>
          <a href="https://example.com" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
          <a href="https://example.com" title="Feedback">Feedback</a>
          <a href="https://example.com" title="Subscribe">Add to Favourites</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS for this is:

```
#mainwrapper header nav {
  /*Nav bar containing links in header */
  background-color: #8fb2d5;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-right: 1%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}
header nav a {
  /* Links in header */
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

I have already tried adding the following:

```
header nav a:hover, header nav a:focus {
  color: #000000;
}
```

and

```
header nav a:hover{
  color: #000000;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I apologise if this is a repeat post but I have looked at other questions/answers with no luck so far.

Comment: This code seems to work for me. You must have an error somewhere else in your code. Please try creating small example code that recreates your issue. It will not only help us but will most likely allow you to find the problem yourself.

Comment: @Ihazkode That shouldn't matter since even though its open, `header nav` should select any `nav` tag inside header even if it is inside another div.

Comment: @ihazkode - Sorry, I've cut that off somehow when putting it in here, it IS closed in my code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `#mainwrapper header nav a:hover` as a selector, that has more specifity.

Comment: This shouldn't matter though unless there is some other selector somewhere else in the CSS that already has higher specificity.

Comment: Perfect! This worked thank you so much. (Feel super dumb for missing that!)

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you need?

```css
#mainwrapper header nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainwrapper">
  <header>
    <div id="logo"><img src="http://www.saltdepot.co.uk/ebay/himalayan/BlogPostAssets/images/logo3.png" alt="Himalayan Salt Store">
      <nav><a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Himalayan-Salt-Store/About-Us.html" title="About Us">About Us</a> <a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Himalayan-Salt-Store/FAQs.html" title="FAQ">FAQ</a>
        <a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Himalayan-Salt-Store/Contact-Us.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="http://feedback.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&userid=saltdepot&ftab=AllFeedback" title="Feedback">Feedback</a>
        <a href="http://my.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?AcceptSavedSeller&sellerid=saltdepot&ssPageName=STRK:MEFS:ADDSTR&rt=nc" title="Subscribe">Add to Favourites</a></nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```